# Magento2: issue with template

Tags: magento2

I have clear Magento and Claue template. Left panel with menu no working.

https://under-wear.pl/

Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try check your js declaration first, could be the inclusion order, let me know after a setup:di:compile, static sources cleaned and cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a div element with the classes `block block-minicart empty ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content` that goes over the menu.

Comment: Marius, thank you for the guidance. do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Not really. Most probably some css magic. I have no idea how the mini cart should look when opened, or even it should be there